# How to invoke cron call of lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda

When I run sls schedule I do not see called lambdas even though I have logs. When I invoke lambda locally with sls invoke local -f launchScrapers it gives me correct log for fake data and lambda itself works, but when I invoke it through sls schedule it prints only Serverless: scheduler: scheduling launch_scrapers/launch_scrapers with */1 * * * * and finishes the process and no logs from invoked lambdas.

```
#This is part from serverless.yml
plugins:
  - serverless-offline-scheduler

launchScrapers:
    handler: handler.launchScrapers
    events:
      - schedule: rate(1 minute)

//This is defined handler
module.exports.launchScrapers = (event, context, callback) => {
  // list business names
  const fakeDatabaseResults = [
    "battleship-missouri-memorial-honolulu",
    "art-institute-of-chicago-chicago-3",
    "lands-end-trail-san-francisco"
  ];

  // launch a lambda for each business name
  fakeDatabaseResults.forEach((businessName) => {
    deployScrapers(businessName);
  });
};
```